# Download an HTML Table after expanding webpage element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking to download the HTML table for a given page on the Vermont SoS after cycling through and expanding all of the "More >>" statements. As it stands, the results are by township and I'm trying to scrape them by precinct.

A sample page can be found here: 
http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/68156

The following code does a good job of extracting the table as is:

```
library(XML)

htmlParse("http://vtelectionarchive.sec.state.vt.us/elections/view/68156/")
```

This is what is produced:

```
$`NULL`
NULL

$precinct_data
                                V1      V2     V3    V4    V5    V6    V7  V8    V9     V10
1                           Totals 123,349 59,432 2,750 2,071 2,024 1,685 126 3,009 194,446
2                          Addison     284    252     2     4     4     2   0     0     548
3                           Albany     186    114     4     6    10     4   0     0     324
4                          Alburgh     383    197    11     7     9     6   0     0     613
5                          Andover     105     96     7     0     2     0   0     0     210
6                        Arlington     477    255    23     4    16     4   0     0     779
7                           Athens      51     39     5     3     0     0   0     0      98
8                      Bakersfield     237    116     6     3     3     4   0     0     369
9                        Baltimore      27     32     6     1     1     1   0     0      68
10                         Barnard     265    143     4     1     6     1   0     0     420
11                          Barnet     353    235     5     6     4    11   0     0     614
```

Yet, I want to include all of the precinct data. How would one go about expanding all of those statements, retaining those cookies, and then exporting the page?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of the issue you are having.

Comment: What is "readHTMLTable" ?

Comment: Sorry about that! I attached the library that's being used.